# How to cluster companies into different types of life cycle?

Tags: time-series, clustering

There is a dataset which contains financial metrics of many companies, for example:

```
    CompanyID   Quarter  Capital        Cash from Investing     Net Loss   ...
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           2012.1   155000000      13933333.33             7148832.346   ...
    1           2012.2   142000000      13865814.7              7226252.159   ...
    1           2012.3   152000000      14026676.28             8101613.457   ...
    ...                                                        
    2           2012.1   178000000      14290357.53             7148832.346   ...
    2           2012.2   198000000      14732687.48             7226252.159   ...
    2           2012.3   187000000      14620640.06             8101613.457   ...
    ...                                                        
    3           2012.1   176000000      16128917.38             7148832.346   ...
    3           2012.2   162000000      17000710.73             7226252.159   ...
    3           2012.3   166000000      14608093.33             8101613.457   ...
    ...
    ...
```

I'd like to cluster these companies into different types of life cycle, i.e. startup, growth, mature and declining.

1. About features selection. This dataset has hundreds of features, should I use algorithms like PCA to process all features which I think are important in this case?
2. About clustering. Should I use time series methods like DTW? Because each company has multiple (dozens of) rows which reflects the financial changes over time.

Any suggested approaches?

Answer (score 0):

By definition of clustering, it is *unsupervised*.

Therefore, clustering cannot "guarantee" to produce lifecycle categories. It is as likely to produce clusters e.g. based on company size or profit, or sector.

If you want lifecycle, use labeled data and classification.